# How to catch .erase exception in vectors?

Tags: c++, qt

I have declared this vector in a code and I want to capture .erase exception in the following situation :

When MyVec has no member and I want to delete one of its indices, it will throw an error. I want to capture this error.

if there's no way to capture this kind of error, Does changing std::vector into alternative ones in Qt like Qlist or ... help to find a solution? what about other alternatives in C++ ?

```
void Main()
{
      std::vector <int> MyVec;
      MyVec.clear();

try    
{

    MyVec.erase(MyVec.begin());
}
catch(...)
{
   qDebug("Hoora I've catched the exception !");
}

}
```

by the way, I'm working in Linux Ubuntu 12.04 and my IDE is Qt 4.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` does not throw an exception when you try to erase an invalid or past-the-end iterator. Instead you just get undefined behaviour.

If you must throw an exception, you can do this:

```
if (MyVec.empty()) {
    throw std::range_error("MyVec is empty");
    // or maybe std::logic_error or std::runtime_error
}
MyVec.erase(MyVec.begin());
```

Remember that exceptions are most useful for non-local handling of exceptional conditions, and try to avoid them if you don't need them. That is, if you can do

```
if (MyVec.empty()) {
    // handle this
} else {
    MyVec.erase(MyVec.begin());
}
```

then it would be much preferable to throwing an exception.

Comment: okay what happens if I use this code in a multi threaded program ? suppose I use Mutex concept for being sure about every usage and again this error happens ? Does this handle the job ?

Comment: @PsP Yes, if multiple threads have access to the vector, I would recommend locking in order to prevent a thread from accessing the vector while another thread is modifying it, or emptying the vector after it's been checked for emptiness but before the erase operation.

Comment: @PsP There may also be other ways to prevent unsafe concurrent access. I don't know; I have very little experience with concurrency.

Comment: @PsP If you have a different question, please ask it separately, or amend your question to include the details of what you intend to do. So far I think you're going down a dangerous path of letting us know only bits and pieces of a larger design that's doomed to failure. You'll get a few details correct, but the design will still collapse because you need to get *all* of it correct, not just some.

Comment: @KubaOber Sorry I was going to ask another question which will explain the real situation better. thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs,

> If the removed elements include the last element in the container, no
>   exceptions are thrown (no-throw guarantee). Otherwise, the container
>   is guaranteed to end in a valid state (basic guarantee). **An invalid**
>   **position or range causes undefined behavior.**

Thus `std::vector::erase` does not necessarily throw an exception if it has no elements. Instead you should check the vector size before erasing.

```
if (!vector.empty()) 
{
  // Erase the entire vector.
  vector.erase(vector.begin(), vector.end());
}
```